# Кроссдоменный запрос для Google Chrome расширения?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, json, php, javascript

**Всем привет!!!**

**Задача:** *передать данные сайтам и получить ответы.*

Использую $.getJSON

```
var options =
    {
      data: 'send data'
    }
    $.getJSON('http://'+mysite+'?callback=?', options,
    function(response)
    {        
        str = parseInt(response.text);        
        chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log(str);
    });
```

Ответ сервера:

```
<?php echo "({ text:'answer data'});"; ?>
```

**Получаю такую ошибку:**

```
Refused to load the script
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".
```

Вписать сайт manifest.json не получиться
по таким причинам запрос нужно передать на разные сайты и сайты не https а обычные http.

Одно из решений проблемы - создание https сайта прописанного в manifest.json который будет выполнять роль посредника между расширением и http сайтами.
Но к сожалению нет возможности создать https сайт.

**Есть ли другие способы решить поставленною задачу?
Спасибо за ответы.**

Comment: > Задача: передать данные сайтам и получить ответы.  

судя по количеству просмотров этого ответа за последние 4 часа, тестировали вы свое расширение именной на этой странице

Comment: Тема очень актуальна меньше чем за 3 часа 4 тысячи просмотров.
Со 2 манифестом много чего изменилось в сторону безопасности,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129077/content-security-policy-cannot-load-google-api-in-chrome-extension

Comment: teanЫЧ, не завидуйте))), hashcode.ru считает только уникальные просмотры. Проблема просто многих волнует и многие ищут её решение. Может быть тут появится решение или способ обойти траблу и тогда 4 тысячи пользователей скажут Хэшкоду БЛАГОДАРЮ!.

Comment: Не думаю, что в воскресенье в 10 часов ночи четыре с половиной тысячи человек __внезапно__ начнут искать решение актуальной проблемы =/  

> считает только уникальные просмотры   

Вот не надо. Был тут у нас один народный умелец (Asen), который писал приложение для хэшкода, у него тоже за пару часиков набегало over9000 просмотров. И тогда сразу стало ясно, как можно накручивать их.  

> не завидуйте)))  

Не смешите  

> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129077/content-security-policy-cannot-load-google-api-in-chrome-extension  

Ну норм. Там за __ПОЛГОДА__ 5.500 просмотров СО ВСЕГО МИРА.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Почему нельзя просто написать в манифест:

```
http://*/*
https://*/*
```

?
[ман](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html)

---

Проверил в Crome 25.0.1364.152m.
Файл **manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name" : "XHR test", 
    "version" : "1.0", 
    "description" : "This is a simple chrome extention for XHR cross-domain test",
    "background" : {
        "scripts": ["event.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "permissions": [
        "https://*/*",
        "http://*/*"
    ]
}
```

Файл **event.js**

```
window.onload = function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "http://ya.ru/", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            console.log( xhr.responseText );
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

Перейдя по **`_generated_background_page.html`** в настройках расширения видим HTML код странички http://ya.ru

Answer (score 0):

Через тэг <script> не получится?

[Вот тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/120336/) ещё можно почитать.

Comment: <script> можно подключить только к локальным файлам.